# AngularJS ng-class not working for conditions

Tags: angularjs, ng-class

This is very straightforward but I am not able to change the class.

I am basically verifying if the date is in correct format (DD-MMM-YYYY hh:mm:ss).

```
<input type="text" style="width : 80%" ng-model="startTime" ng-class="{invalid: !isValid ,valid: isValid}" />
```

where isValid is a scope variable which evaluates to true and false. The css class is not applied.

Here is the [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZAZU71RYM0JY2okOWPWI?p=preview).

Answer (score 5):

It is working.  Inspect the element.  Your bootstrap classes are overwriting it.  Try this:

```
 .invalid {
    background-color: #FA787E !important;
  }

 .valid {
    background-color: #78FA89 !important;
}
```

Comment: Yes. Just figured that out . The !important was important. Thanks